# My conda installation is opening up a chromium browser by default

Tags: installation, anaconda, conda, chromium, sts

I am on my (base) environment.

All of my conda installation is leading me to open up a Chromium browser controlled by test software and I'm not sure what to do.

Here is a video: https://www.loom.com/share/d2c4f3a22bc84d239c86ffcba6807a81

I have the following hidden files in my home directory.
[image]

Comment: Do you ahve any proxy configured?

Comment: How do I check that? Also, the issue around opening the chromium browser has now been solved by deleting the folder the company made me install in my `opt` folder. However, now when I run `conda list -envs` it takes ages to find my environment. What is going wrong?